# cross compiling libc for x86_64-linux-android

Tags: c, compilation, libc

I am cross compiling (using x86_64-linux-android-gcc) to build GNU libc, GLIBC version 2.32,  for x86_64-linux-android.  Getting the error "inconsistent operand constraints in an __asm" from the compilation of strtod_l.c.  In strtod_l.c, is a function round_and_return() which makes a call to the macro math_force_eval(force_underflow).  This macro is defined in "math-barriers.h", and the error happens at this line:

```
    __asm __volatile ("" : : "f" (x));
```

This triggered me to try and discover what the value of force_underflow is:
Tried adding these lines to strtod_l.c and got these errors: 
printf(“force_underflow=%f\n”,force_underflow); 
Error: %f is type double, force_underflow is type long double 
Tried: 
printf(“force_underflow=%lf\n”,force_underflow); 
Error: %lf is type double, force_underflow is type long double
Tried:
 printf(“force_underflow=%Lf\n”,force_underflow);
Error: %Lf is type long double, force_underflow is type double

Which brings me to my first question: how can the variable "force_underflow" be both type "double" and type "long double"?  And is there something in the line of code:

```
   __asm __volatile("" : : "f" (x));
```

that can be altered to satisfy the compiler?  Thanks for any/all suggestions!

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64-linux-android-gcc` is not a suitable compiler for compiling glibc; it targets the `x86_64-linux-android` ABI, not the `x86_64-linux-gnu` ABI. In order to compile glibc, you need a `linux-gnu` targeting toolchain.

I don't have prior awareness of the details of the former ABI, but from the error messages, it sounds like x86 Android does not have a distinct `long double` representation but defines it as a the same thing as `double`. But this is just one of many forms of breakage you might get from using the wrong-target compiler. Other breakage might even be silent. You just need to build the proper cross toolchain for your target.

Comment: Thanks for that great info.  I built the x86_64-linux-android cross-compiler as my target platform is Google Pixel for some software which needs libpthread.a (from GNU libc).  I'll have to rethink things now...